# Column containing LazyColumn and a TextField will hide the TextField

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have 2 elements in compose for the message list and the input. When I'm using the `Column` for the parent the result will be like the below:

```
@Composable
fun MessageList(messageList: List<MessagePresenter>) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        LazyColumn{
            items(messageList) { message ->
                TextMessageItem(message)
            }
        }
        val text = remember { mutableStateOf("Type Something...") }

        MessengerInput(text = text)
    }
}
```

The result has no input:
[image]

The question is why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this helpful to add a `weight` to our `LazyColumn`:

```
@Composable
fun MessageList(messageList: List<MessagePresenter>) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)){
            items(messageList) { message ->
                TextMessageItem(message)
            }
        }
        val text = remember { mutableStateOf("Type Something...") }

        MessengerInput(text = text)
    }
}
```

The result will be like this:
[image]